# how to get specific value from json and to show in html using angularjs ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, angularjs

I am new to angularjs, I am facing some issues on getting and displaying one specific value from json file to show on my view page using angularjs ng-repeat for image source. Based on this key/value only I need to repeat the json file and need to get and display the specific value on my html page.

JSON:

```
[
    {"name":"imageurl","value":"/images/Image1.nii"},
    {"name":"3d","value":"3d0"},
    {"name":"sliceX","value":"sliceX0"},
    {"name":"sliceY","value":"sliceY0"},
    {"name":"sliceZ","value":"sliceZ0"},
    {"name":"imageurl","value":"/images/Image2.nii"},
    {"name":"3d","value":"3d1"},
    {"name":"sliceX","value":"sliceX1"},
    {"name":"sliceY","value":"sliceY1"},
    {"name":"sliceZ","value":"sliceZ1"}
]
```

Here i need to repeat through key: imageurl and to display it's value on my html page. For first iteration, it should get first imageurl(like: /images/Image1.nii), and for second iteration, it should get second imageurl(like: /images/Image2.nii) value, and so on... I've created a fiddle at: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pw0pqg4g/5/) . Please check once. So my desired output could be:

On first iteration:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in newArr>     
    <div data-imgsrc="/images/Image1.nii">     
        <div id="3d0"></div>    
        <div id="sliceX0"></div>    
        <div id="sliceY0"></div>    
        <div id="sliceZ0"></div>    
    </div>    
</div>
```

on second iteration:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in newArr>     
    <div data-imgsrc="/images/Image2.nii">     
        <div id="3d1"></div>    
        <div id="sliceX1"></div>    
        <div id="sliceY1"></div>    
        <div id="sliceZ1"></div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Please help me regarding this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change data structure, right now it makes little sense for the your task. Nesting 3D, X, Y and Z objects inside each imageurl objects would makes everything very simple:

```
[
    {"name":"imageurl","value":"/images/Image1.nii", parts: [
        {"name":"3d","value":"3d0"},
        {"name":"sliceX","value":"sliceX0"},
        {"name":"sliceY","value":"sliceY0"},    
        {"name":"sliceZ","value":"sliceZ0"},
    ]},

    {"name":"imageurl","value":"/images/Image2.nii", parts: [
        {"name":"3d","value":"3d1"},
        {"name":"sliceX","value":"sliceX1"},
        {"name":"sliceY","value":"sliceY1"},
        {"name":"sliceZ","value":"sliceZ1"}
    ]}
]
```

and then you would render it like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in newArr>     
    <div data-imgsrc="{{item.value}}">
        <div ng-repeat="part in item.parts" id="{{part.value}}"></div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Hi dfsq, Thanks for your reply, I will check this and let you know asap. Thanks