# Creating Tile Map from JSON using AngularJS ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, arrays, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to create a tile map for a game using ng-repeat and am having trouble with the ng-repeat code responsible for individual tiles in a row. If this was vanilla JS I'd be having no trouble but this has been bugging me for a while now. [I found this answer which seems really close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32578064/how-to-get-specific-value-from-json-and-to-show-in-html-using-angularjs-ng-repea) to what I'm looking for but I haven't been able to figure out how to apply it to my particular JSON file.

**HTML**

```
<div class='map' ng-controller='map'>
    <div class='map-row' ng-repeat='row in rows'>
        <div class='map-tile' ng-repeat='row in rows'>
            {{ row.data[$index] }}
        </div><!-- end of .map-tile -->
    </div><!-- end of .map-row -->
</div><!-- end of .map -->
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('map', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/map.json')
    .success(function(response) {
        $scope.rows = response.rows;
    });
});
```

**JSON**

```
{
    "rows": [ 
        {
            "data":[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
        },
        {
            "data":[1, 0, 0, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
        },
        {
            "data":[1, 0, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
        },
        {
            "data":[1, 0, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
        }
}
```

(Truncated to save space.)

**Result**

[image]

The problem with the result is that the ng-repeat instruction is iterating over each row incorrectly - I can't figure out what I should put into the second ng-repeat on this line instead of 'row in rows':

```
<div class='map-tile' ng-repeat='row in rows'>
```

Below is an image highlighting the array items that are showing up in the output for each row:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you guessed, the problem is with the `ng-repeat` that iterates over the columns.

Your HTML should look like this:

```
<div class='map' ng-controller='map'>
  <div class='map-row' ng-repeat='row in rows'>
    <div class='map-tile' ng-repeat='col in row.data track by $index'>
        {{ col }}
    </div><!-- end of .map-tile -->
  </div><!-- end of .map-row -->
</div><!-- end of .map -->
```

The first `ng-repeat` loops through the rows. The second `ng-repeat` should loop through the `data` array in each row.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was thinking about the array rows vs cols thing wrong, so your answer really clarifies that. Unfortunately with regard to the angular syntax, when I test your answer, I get a 'duplicate key in repeater' error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=col%20in%20row.data&p1=number:1&p2=1. So I am still hunting for the right way to type this when using ng-repeat, but at least I'm visualising the arrays correctly now :)

Comment: Oh yes. You have to add a `track by $index` since the `data` array has duplicate values (numbers). Updated the answer now.